# Prove that if x and y are odd natural numbers, then $x^2+y^2$ is never a perfect square.

Tags: number-theory

Prove that if x and y are odd natural numbers, then $x^2+y^2$ is never a perfect square.

Let $x=2m+1$ and $y=2l+1$ where m,l are integers.

$x^2+y^2=(2m+1)^2+(2l+1)^2=4(m^2+m+l^2+l)+2$

Where do I go from here?

Comment: Now you can see every perfect square must be of the form $4k$ or $4k+1$.

Comment: Hint: $x^2+y^2$ is an even number that is _not_ a multiple of $4$. But the square of an odd number is odd, while the square of an even number must be a multiple of $4$, no?

Answer (score 5):

You can now look at all the natural numbers modulo $4$. We know that numbers must either be even or odd, hence they have the form
$$2n\text{ or } 2n+1.$$
In modulo $4$, they are just $2n\text{ or } 2n+1\mod4$. Now, look at the squares of these numbers, we have that 
$$(2n)^2\equiv 4n^2\equiv0\mod4.$$
Also, the odds give
$$(2n+1)^2\equiv 4n^2+4n+1\equiv1\mod4.$$

Now we know that squares MUST be either $0$ or $1$ modulo $4$. What is your number modulo $4$?

Answer (score 1):

The square of an integer is congruent to 0 or 1 (mod 4). In fact an even number (remember the sum is even) will always be congruent to 0 (mod 4). What you end up with is congruent to 2 (mod 4), which means it's not a perfect square.

Answer (score 1):

When a perfect square number is divided by 4 it doesn't leave a remainder of 2- GANESHA A S